# Angular DataTable - Date Time column sort issue

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I am using Angular DataTable where I am trying to sort the dates(YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS) and I have transformed them using date pipe into this `dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm a` format. but it is not sorting the dates properly.

I am receiving the response from api like this:

> {   DateTime: "2021-06-28T10:45:24.49",Product: "Product
> 1",PurchasedBy: "Jones" }

I am converting the datetime property using date pipe in my html.

> {{data.DateTime | datetransform |  date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a'  }}

And my Angular DataTable looks like this:

[image: Angular Data Table]

If you go through the image I have selected the column to be in descending order but the sorting is not happening properly.

I need help with this.
Any working example would really be appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by providing code in the question or [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com)?

Comment: @YongShun I have added the basic problem with the api response and table.. please look into it

Comment: if your data.DateTime is a Date object of javaScript (or a string in format yyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss) you should not have any problem, see a fool example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqam1n?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html. And this is the approach you should make:, transform your data in the way that the dateTime was a Date

Comment: Ok. I will try with this. Thanks for the response